# MySQL 5.7 - ¿Se puede cambiar el dueño de los todos los procedimientos almancenados de manera masiva?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Trabajo con múltiples entornos de una misma base de datos: Un servidor dedicado a pruebas del usuario (uno estable) y dispongo de un entorno local en mi equipo de trabajo.

Hay ocasiones donde, literalmente, me cargo mi propia bd y debo levantar un respaldo, el cual tomo del equipo de pruebas de usuario.

El problema comienza cuando termino de levantar el respaldo en mi equipo local, pues recibo un "The user specified as a definer ('testUser'@'%') does not exist".

Esto sucede porque en el entorno de pruebas hay 2 "testuser", uno para localhost y otro para % (cualquier dominio), pero en mi equipo local no dispongo de un "testUser" para cualquier dominio.

Si bien duplicar el usuario en mi ambiente local soluciona el tema del error
¿Existe alguna forma para cambiar de manera masiva el `DEFINER=testUser@%` de todas las rutinas de la base de datos por el usuario que yo desee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resulta que tras investigar un poco en la comunidad en inglés, encontré que si es posible.

La tabla `mysql.proc` da información sobre todos los procedimientos almacenados de todas las bases de datos del servidor.

Para confirmar hice primero un

```
#   OBTENER TODAS LAS RUTINAS DE MI BASE
SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`proc` AS `rutinas` WHERE (`rutinas`.`db` = 'MI_BASE_DE_DATOS');
```

Y en efecto, me devolvió las rutinas de la base de datos, entre sus columnas estaba la que me interesaba: 'definer'. Al final solo tuve que hacer un update común y silvestre:

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` SET `definer` = 'testUser@localhost'
WHERE (
    (`db` = 'MI_BASE_DE_DATOS')
    AND
    (`definer` = 'testUser@%')  #   CAMBIAR UNICAMENTE LAS QUE TIENEN EL USUARIO QUE NO FUNCIONA
);
```

Es posible consultar las rutinas que pertenecen a un usuarrio en específico filtrando por la columna `definer`

```
#   OBTENER TODAS LAS RUTINAS DE MI BASE POR DUEÑO
SELECT *
FROM `mysql`.`proc` AS `rutinas`
WHERE (
    (`rutinas`.`db` = 'MI_BASE_DE_DATOS')
    AND
    (`rutinas`.`definer` = 'USUARIO@DOMINIO')   #   EN MI CASO ERA testUser@%
);
```

Edición: Fue necesario reiniciar mi base de datos desde MySQL Notifier para que el cambio surgiera efecto. Agregué una consulta para buscar rutinas por usuario en específico.

Dejo por acá [la fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144239/change-the-owner-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure) de mi solución.